# Deleting A Specified Element In An Array Using Random Class

Tags: c#

```
class Check
{
     public static void Main()
     {         
              int[] arr1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
              Console.WriteLine("The Number That Left Us Is");
              Random rnd = new Random();
              int r = rnd.Next(arr1.Length);
              int Left = (arr1[r]);
              Console.WriteLine(Left);
      }
 }
```

If 2 is generated i want the 2 to be removed and the remaining i have to be left with should be 1 and 3.
Can anyone help. Can it be done in array.

Comment: Must you use an array, could you use a `List<int>` instead? That would make this very easy if you could.

Comment: I gotta stick with the arrays

Comment: I don't get why it should be an array, but i would store them in a HashSet<int> (if the numbers are unique), because with the random you want to remove a value, not an index. And a hashSet works fast with indexing values. Searching/adding/removing..

Answer (score 2):

Arrays can not be re-sized, one you set them they are that size forever.

The "best" option is use a `List<int>` instead of an `int[]`

```
class Check
{
     public static void Main()
     {         
              List<int> arr1 = List<int>int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
              Console.WriteLine("The Number That Left Us Is");
              Random rnd = new Random();
              int r = rnd.Next(arr1.Length);
              int Left = (arr1[r]);
              arr1.RemoveAt(r);
              Console.WriteLine(Left);
      }
 }
```

To actually create a new array of one size smaller will take more code.

```
class Check
{
     public static void Main()
     {         
              int[] arr1 = int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
              Console.WriteLine("The Number That Left Us Is");
              Random rnd = new Random();
              int r = rnd.Next(arr1.Length);
              int Left = (arr1[r]);

              int oldLength = arr1.Length;
              arrTmp = arr1;                  
              arr1 = new int[oldLength - 1];
              Array.Copy(arrTmp, arr1, r);
              Array.Copy(arrTmp, r+1, arr1, r, oldLength - r - 1);

              Console.WriteLine(Left);
      }
 }
```

---

You mention "You gotta stick with the arrays", it is VERY easy to turn the list in to an array

```
class Check
{
     public static void Main()
     {         
              List<int> arr1 = List<int>int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
              Console.WriteLine("The Number That Left Us Is");
              Random rnd = new Random();
              int r = rnd.Next(arr1.Length);
              int Left = (arr1[r]);
              arr1.RemoveAt(r);
              Console.WriteLine(Left);
              SomeFunctionThatTakesAnArrayAsAnArgument(arr1.ToArray());
      }
 }
```

Comment: You can resize one dimensional arrays with .net see the following articles http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx and simple examples http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-resize

Comment: @Marko `Array.Resize` is new to .NET 4.0, and it is just a wrapper doing [exactly the same thing I did in my code](http://typedescriptor.net/browse/members/245133-System.Array.Resize%5BT%5D%28T%5B%5D&,Int32%29) except it removes from the end, if you want to resize from the middle like your code you are going to need to do two copy operations like I show in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays cannot be resized, if you want to remove items use a `List<T>`.

However, you can create a new one. If you want to keep all items but one at the random index:

```
arr1 = arr1.Where((i, index) => index != r).ToArray();
```

With a list you can use [`RemoveAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z.aspx) which is more efficient than creating arrays:

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
list.RemoveAt(r);
```

Comment: It seems to me that this code there remains the element 2 in arr1 and not the reverse

Comment: No, it removes one element which is at the index of the random int. See: http://ideone.com/ePBbPC

Comment: Yeeeesss I have not seen the not symbole, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays can't be dynamically resized in .NET, so you can't really 'remove' an item from an array (you could set it to 0, but I don't think that's what you want).

Try using a `List<int>` instead:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
Console.WriteLine("The Number That Left Us Is");
Random rnd = new Random();
int r = rnd.Next(list.Count);
int Left = (list[r]);
list.Remove(Left);
Console.WriteLine(Left);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to following it removes the item from the list and creates a new array without the specific item.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
       int[] arr1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
      Console.WriteLine("The Number That Left Us Is");
      Random rnd = new Random();
      int r = rnd.Next(arr1.Length);

      // Create a new array except the item in the specific location
      arr1 = arr1.Except(new int[]{arr1[r]}).ToArray();
      int Left = (arr1[r]);
      Console.WriteLine(Left);
}
```